# Apply function across windows

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, parent

Let's say that the main window (w2) is inserted vía iFrame (w1) to a page where I can't modify source code. When you submit a form in w2, a third iFrame (w3) is inserted. When I wrote the code, w1 didn't exist. What I need is that from w3 a function is called (affecting w2) but keep (w1) working. This is the code which worked without w1

```
var cross = "javascript: window.parent.$('#"+div_id+"').html(document.body.innerHTML); void(0);";
```

Thanks!
:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with `window.parent`

```
var cross = "javascript:"+
    window.parent.$('#"+div_id+"').html(document.body.innerHTML);"+
    "void(0);";
```